# Deferreds vs $.ajax done/fail

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

What exactly should I use for standalone asynchronous operations; deferred objects or is ajax `done()`/`fail()` enough? What is the difference?

I understand that `deferred.when()` is useful as it allows us to know when all of **multiple** async operations are completed. But **what about one** async operation? `done()`/`fail()` allows me to know when it is completed too.

Comment: `$.ajax()` method returns a `$.Deferred()` object. So you are using deferreds in all cases. You can make your own deferred but ajax will return the same automatically. This is only with jQuery, vanilla javascript have not this functionality

Comment: Better I add an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$.ajax()` method returns a `$.Deferred()` object. So you are using deferreds in all cases. You can make your own deferred but ajax will return the same automatically. This is only with jQuery, vanilla javascript have not this functionality.

`$.ajax()` will return the following promise methods:

`fail()`, `done()`, `always()` and `then()`.

---

**What Jquery forum says:**

> The jqXHR objects returned by $.ajax() as of jQuery 1.5 implement the Promise interface, giving them all the properties, methods, and behavior of a Promise

Detailed reference to jQuery `$.ajax` is available here, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

From the [Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/):

> jQuery.Deferred() introduces several enhancements to the way callbacks
>   are managed and invoked. In particular, jQuery.Deferred() provides
>   flexible ways to provide multiple callbacks, and these callbacks can
>   be invoked regardless of whether the original callback dispatch has
>   already occurred.

And:

> One model for understanding Deferred is to think of it as a chain-aware function wrapper.

So like you said, the big difference is that the `deferred.when` is useful when handling multiple requests. Answering your question, for standalone operations, `done()` and `fail()` will do just fine, and are easier to implement, in my opinion c: